# Создание flash сайта

Tags: flash

Какой программой можно сделать сайт типа такого http://www.dasai.es/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На Adobe Flash к примеру...Хотя я больше и не знаю програм которые так могут делать...Скорей всего он.

Comment: Логично предположить что кроме него не что не сможет так сделать...Так как это воспроизводит Adobe Flash Player :)

Comment: Он сложный?

Comment: Не особо - там даже без особых знаний можно какой нибудь банер слепить...А вот насчёт сайта...Не когда на нём не пробывал сайты делать...Думаю начальная подготовка в нём нужна будет...И ещё я знаю что он со всеми норм Веб-Языками дружит...Тоесть без проблем можно в него php засунуть :)

Comment: Средствами обычного `Adobe Flash` было бы очень неудобно писать сайт такого типа как в примере. **Тут все-таки нужна `IDE`, более ориентированная на код, чем на работу с `assets`.**

Answer (score 2):

Промышленными стандартами в плане разработки на `ActionScript` являются, насколько мне известно, [**Adobe Flash Builder**](http://www.adobe.com/ru/products/flash-builder.html) и [**FDT.**](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/) *Разумеется, для генерации `asset'ов` в таком случае используется классический [**Adobe Flash.**](http://www.adobe.com/ru/products/flash.html?promoid=BPCEO)*

---

Есть конечно и умельцы, которые используют `vim` и `IntelliJ IDEA` для того, чтобы писать `ActionScript` код, но это скорее исключение, чем правило.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу уточнить, в данном случае еще использовался 3д движок (engine) на ActionScript 3.0, там кроме навыков ООП программирования, необходимы смоделированные/текстурированные и подготовленные модели (земля, самолет, джойстик и т.д.) в каком нибудь 3д редакторе (Blender3D, 3ds MAX). Плюс написание такого приложения ближе по парадигме к 3д играм (хоть и очень простым) чем к веб-сайтам как таковым (хтмл, яваскрипт, дизайн, сss). Например [такой сайт](http://oxanaratone.narod.ru/cityone/cityone_concept.html) набрасывается в Flash Builder за час-два, хтмл и другую обвязку он генерит сам. Моделинг в 3д редакторе занял времени поболе.